# "There is ... here" vs "Here is a book"

Tags: word-order

What is the difference between these two?

1. There is a book **here**.
2. **Here** is a book.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343427/here-are-word-order/343428#343428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, they could mean almost the same thing, though the second one is more often used in the context of presenting a book to the other person.

Both of them can mean "A book is present in this place". However, a native speaker would usually use the first example "There is a book here" to indicate that.

The second sentence has the same meaning when taken literally, but it is usually used to present something and usually further context will imply that the other person is meant to take the book. Though sometimes, the second version will be used simply to indicate that a book is there, especially if it is done in a dramatic fashion.

Comment: Thanks. "There is a book" is considered incomplete?

Comment: @PetrVatov In a strict grammatical sense, no.  That could be a complete sentence. But it merely states a book exists, which isn't particularly meaningful in the context of books. "There is a way." is not uncommon for instance and "There is another" was rather famously used in Star Wars. But since it would be so weird in the context of books, I think most people hearing it would either expect more or expect the context to provide an implied continuation.

Comment: In an appropriate context, "There is a book" is possible, e.g. A: What' on the shelf, Ed?" B: "Well, there's a few ornaments and a vase of flowers, and there's a book".

Comment: "I don't know if there is a film but there is a book". In conversation, pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

"*There is a book here*" indicates the fact that a book exists, and that the book is here.

"*Here is a book*" has more than one function.

The most similar function to the first sentence is *pointing out* or *indicating the discovery* of a book.

It also can be used when *offering*, *giving* or *handing* someone a book.